# how to access this kind of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest-client

I am using RestClient to make a post request and i made it so i an error response back so i can print those error messages in console

i tried the following per the restclient gem documentation

```
begin
  response = RestClient.post base_uri, params.to_json, content_type: 'application/json', accept: 'application/json'
rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => err
  error = err.response
  p "this is the error response #{error}"
end
```

when i print err.response i get the following

`"this is the error response {\"error\":{\"message\":\"An active access token must be used to query information about the current us
er.\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":2500,\"fbtrace_id\":\"HTzmJ0CcIfd\"}}"`

how do i access the message in the above hash to display it in console?

tried

`p "this is the error response #{error.message}"`

and it gives me `"Bad request"` - have no idea where it gets that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to output it:

```
error = JSON.load(err.response)

puts error['error']['message']
```

You can always format it a bit better:

```
puts '[Code %d %s] %s' % [
  error['error']['code'],
  error['error']['type'],
  error['error']['message']
]
```

Note that using `puts` inside of a Rails process is not going to work very well. You might want to use `Rails.logger.debug` instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for response tried the above, but gives me an empty string `"this is the error response "` this is weird. tried with both puts and Rails.logger.debug

Comment: ah it says its a `string`

Comment: Ah, I just looked at the content more closely, answer updated. If you're doing a lot of HTTP calls with JSON, try [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday).

Comment: thank you this did the trick! btw when do i use Rails.logger.debug? does it save a log somewhere?

Comment: It goes into `log/development.log` in development mode. In production `debug` level messages are usually ignored to keep the logs cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The response you received is in JSON.  You'll need to decode the JSON first and then interact with the data.  Personally, I like [MultiJson](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json) for this:

```
begin
  response = RestClient.post base_uri, params.to_json, content_type: 'application/json', accept: 'application/json'
rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => err
  error = MultiJson.load(err.response)
  p "this is the error response #{error[:message]}"
end
```